# How do i get rid of PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: when i'm trying to download MNIST ORIGINAL dataset from sklearn.datasets?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata

data = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='/scikit_learn_data')
```

---

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6815328d5a62> in <module>()
----> 1 data = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='/scikit_learn_data')

/Users/soufianefhiyil/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/mldata.py in fetch_mldata(dataname, target_name, data_name, transpose_data, data_home)
    128 
    129     # check if this data set has been already downloaded
--> 130     data_home = get_data_home(data_home=data_home)
    131     data_home = join(data_home, 'mldata')
    132     if not exists(data_home):

/Users/soufianefhiyil/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py in get_data_home(data_home)
     93     data_home = expanduser(data_home)
     94     if not exists(data_home):
---> 95         makedirs(data_home)
     96     return data_home
     97 

/Users/soufianefhiyil/anaconda/lib/python3.6/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    218             return
    219     try:
--> 220         mkdir(name, mode)
    221     except OSError:
    222         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/scikit_learn_data'
```

Comment: try using `sudo`

Comment: Try not storing to the file system root. Use something in your home directory for a preference.